# how do i valid a user name containing only [a:z] or number and start with [a:z] in flutter

Tags: flutter, validation

how do I valid a user name containing only [a:z] or number and start with [a:z] in flutter

```
child: TextFormField(
              autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                validator: (value){
                  if(value.)
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(35.0)),
                    ),
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    hintText: 'User Name',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value.isEmpty
      ? 'Enter Your Name'
       : RegExp(
        '!@#<>?":_``~;[]\|=-+)(*&^%1234567890')
        ? 'Enter a Valid Name'
         : null
```

Comment: i do not understand this is the section :  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                validator: (value){
                  if(value.)
                }, what shoud i do

Comment: validator: (value) {
                        Pattern pattern = r'^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:[ _-][A-Za-z0-9]+)*$';
                        RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern); //check for asking
                        if (value.isEmpty)
                          return 'required*';
                        else if (!regex.hasMatch(value))
                          return 'Invalid username';
                        else
                          return null;
                      }, i tried this worked